# Delete a line that contains more than 1 specific string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I use `'/'"$name"'/d'` for deleting the line that contains a user input name variable. But I want to delete the line that contains `$name` and `$surname` together. How can I modify this `'/'"$name"'/d'` code?

Answer (score 1):

Can do it with sed like this :

```
cat input | sed '/\('"$name"'.*'"$surname"'\)\|\('"$surname"'.*'"$name"'\)/d'
```

Comment: depends if you have a file or a stream. Thats pointless regarding the question. We dont even know if John uses a stream of a file.

Comment: `cat` is also not used for a stream.

Comment: You dont get it : cat creates a stream from a file, so my example of sed command works with both. `cat` is just there to create a context, not to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

easiest would be

```
cat input | egrep -v "$name.*$surname" | egrep -v "$surname.*$name" > output
```

Comment: @kurumi, please have a look at the OP's track record in questions asked - the dumb solution might trick him out of copy&paste mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/name/ && /surname/ {next} 1' filename
```

or, to pass the values from the shell into awk

```
awk -v first=$name -v last=$surname '$0 ~ first && $0 ~ last {next} 1' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'next if /'"$name"'/ && /'"$surname"'/;print' file
```